# Check for valid date - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation, days

Guys my primary objective is to avoid invalid days.

In sheet 1 i have:

- A1 data validation with years (from 1900-2019)
- B1 data validation with all months
- C1 i use change event (if both fields A1 & A2 are not empty) calculate how many days the selected month has based on the selected year and create a data validation includes all available days.

For days calculation i use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ndays As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ndays = Day(DateSerial(.Range("A1").Value, .Range("B1").Value + 1, 1) - 1)

    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet Structure:**

[image]

Is there a batter way to calculate days?

Comment: I would not imagine you requiring VBA for this, have you thought about creating a [dynamic data validation list](https://excelsemipro.com/2011/05/a-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) using named ranges?

Comment: Why is your code using **B1** when the data is in **A2** ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent i edit the question cause the previous one includes mistakes. i also upload photo and my code. Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use:

- `DateValue()` function to build a date out of a string you compose with your year and month values and adding any valid day number (I chose "1" to be sure...)
- `EOMONTH()` worksheet function to get the last day of the resulting date month:

like follows:

```
With someSheet
    ...
    nb_days = Day(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateValue(.Range("A1").Value & " " & .Range("B1").Value & " 1"), 0))
    ...
End With
```

Comment: NB, in your second example the ranges aren't qualified with the sheet (no dots)

Comment: @DisplayName could you please see updated question? i try to clear the question because i receive an error type 13..

Comment: @Error1004, see edited answer as per your edited question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the UDF (User Defined Function) below.

```
Function MonthDays(Rng As Range) As Integer

    Const Y As Integer = 1
    Const M As Integer = 2

    Dim Arr As Variant

    Application.Volatile                    ' recalculates on every change
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Rng) = 2 Then
        Arr = Rng.Value
        MonthDays = DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Arr(Y, 1), Arr(M, 1), 1), _
                                  DateSerial(Arr(Y, 1), Arr(M, 1) + 1, 1))
    End If
End Function
```

You can call it directly from the worksheet with a function call like `=MonthDays(A1:A2)` where A1 holds the year and A2 holds the month. If either is missing the function returns 0. The function accepts impossible numbers for both year and month and will return a logical result, such as the 14th month of a year being the following year's February. However, you can limit the entries by data validation.

All UDFs can be called as normal functions from your code. `Cells(3, 1).Value = MonthDays(Range("A1:A2"))` would have the same effect as entering the function call as described in the preceding paragraph in A3. However, if the function is called from VBA the line `Application.Volatile` would be not required (ineffective).

Comment: FWIW I think `Application.Volatile` is redundant here; if I remember correctly UDFs are recalculated according to the same rules as normal worksheet functions - i.e whenever a precedent changes (`Rng` changes). In my experience `Application.Volatile` is generally only useful for UDFs taking no arguments or that work with time/ random numbers. In OP's case you only want the function to recalculate when a different month is selected, which should happen automatically